# Copy Azure SQL Database Between Azure Subscriptions

Tags: azure-sql-database

Getting straight to the point, is this even possible?

I have successfully copied an Azure SQL database within the same subscription.  In doing so, I kept it simple by copying the database to the same server (within the subscription).  I used the Powershell commands `Add-AzureRmAccount` and `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy`.

I have tried executing the `Add-AzureRmAccount` twice (once for each subscription) but this seems to replace the first subscription with the second in the context as the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy` command reports that it cannot find the specified resource group (which exists in the source subscription).

All that said, if this is something that is possible, what are the steps / commands that I need to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Azure SQL Server on a different resource group.

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -Location "East US" -AdministratorLogin "AdminLogin" -AdministratorLoginPassword "AdminPassword"
```

Copy the source database to the newly created Azure SQL Server.

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "SourceServer" -DatabaseName "Orders" -PartnerServer "NewlyCreatedServer" -PartnerDatabase "OrdersCopy"
```

Move the resource group of the Newly created Azure SQL Server to another subscription.

> Move-AzureRmResource
>       -DestinationResourceGroupName 
>       [-DestinationSubscriptionId ]
>       -ResourceId 
>       [-Force]
>       [-ApiVersion ]
>       [-Pre]
>       [-DefaultProfile ]
>       [-InformationAction ]
>       [-InformationVariable ]
>       [-WhatIf]
>       [-Confirm]
>       []

Comment: It appears that the last command will not work in my case as the subscriptions I am copying between are not under the same tenant ID.  At any rate, I marked your solution as the accepted answer as I think it would have worked otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Just to let you know you can use SQL Data Sync between subscriptions. On the destination recreate the same schema and start SQL Data Sync.

Comment: I believe Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy has been renamed to New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `CREATE DATABASE`, as per [Richard Hauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33329350/183373) on Stackoverflow (which I executed from SQL Server Management Studio v17.5):

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original;
```

Some important notes:

- SQL admin account and password were the same on both servers.
- Servers were in different subscriptions.
- Servers were on the same Tenant, checked via Azure PowerShell console with:

  ```
  (Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <your-source-subscription>).TenantId 
  (Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <your-destination-subscription>).TenantId
  ```

You can monitor the progress with:

```
SELECT state_desc, name 
FROM sys.databases
```

Reference Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-azure-sql-database?view=azure-sqldw-latest#creating-a-copy-of-a-database-on-another-server
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy

Comment: Similar to the previous answer, this *might* have worked for me had the two subscriptions been created under the same tenant ID.  Since they are not, I doubt that it will work as you listed this as one of the requirements.

Comment: I like the ARM template approach in the same SO question that you link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648302/73226

Answer (score 0):

`Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy` has been renamed to `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy`

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy
   [-DatabaseName] <String>
   [-Tags <Hashtable>]
   [-CopyResourceGroupName <String>]
   [-CopyServerName <String>]
   -CopyDatabaseName <String>
   [-AsJob]
   -ComputeGeneration <String>
   -VCore <Int32>
   [-LicenseType <String>]
   [-ServerName] <String>
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

[Using Azure to create a copy of SQL Database from a snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabasecopy?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: This won't solve the problem of moving between subscriptions, which was the question. "The Azure portal, PowerShell, and the Azure CLI do not support database copy to a different subscription." - from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Came here via a search engine and notice that the Azure documentation now supports a way to copy databases to different subscriptions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell#copy-to-a-different-subscription